# Unable to get rid of all anaconda traces after uninstalling

Tags: macos, anaconda, zsh, macos-big-sur

0

I have been trying to entirely get rid of Anaconda. I am using macOS Big Sur and after following the instructions on their website, it appeared that nothing changed and that it was still installed along with its packages. I have also deleted the backup file and the lines that related to conda in my .bash_profile file. I have eventually found an "opt" file under "Macintosh HD" in which I have found an "anaconda3" directory (in addition to the one that was in the Users home directory that got deleted). After deleting that directory it seemed that it has worked (terminal doesn't recognise conda commands anymore). I have found however that my PATH is still affected by it. First, my terminal prompt starts with "(base)". And when I enter echo $PATH in my command line this is what I get: "/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Is this going to be a problem? How do solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have been using **Anaconda-Clean**
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/
Maybe it's not too late yet.

Comment: I did initially. I followed the instructions on this page to the letter and it didn't work. It changed nothing. I spent a few hours on this.